# View all rows where at least one column in a subset of columns contains zero

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), envr_val1 = c(0:9), envr_val2 = c(1:9,0), 
count = round(rnorm(mean = 10, sd = 10, n = 10)))
```

I want to find all the rows where at least one of  `envr_val1` or `envr_val2` are 0, but not where `count` is zero.

In the real dataset, the number of columns I am looking in is large, so I have the names of the columns of interest saved in an object:

```
colzerofix <- c('envr_val1', 'envr_val2')
```

Things I have tried:

```
df[colzerofix == 0,]
df[which(pmin(unlist(df[,colzerofix]))==0),]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[Reduce("|", lapply(colzerofix, function(x) df[,x] == 0)) & df$count != 0,]
#OR
df[rowSums(df[colzerofix] == 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0 & df$count != 0,]
```

Comment: Both of these work perfectly for the example data (although I removed the `df$count` arguments, I just meant that I didn't want to look at `count` not that it couldn't be zero). However, neither is working with my full dataset. The first one is returning the following error: `28 arguments passed to '|' which requires 2`, I assume because of the number of columns I'm telling it to look at. The second option is returning nothing but `NA` rows (rownames are NA and all values are NA).